# Subversion issue with working copy at a single revision

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm using subclipse to merge changes from the trunk into a branch and during the "best practices" step, there's a notification that the working copy is not at a single revision. None of the files or folders in the package explorer have the dirty indicator and (having been through this before) even after doing an update, none of the version numbers appear to have changed. What specifically is subclipse looking at to generate this notification? Is there something I can also run from the command line to corroborate this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It basically means you have a "Mixed Revision Working Copy" which is very normal and common.  If you Google it you will find a lot of explanations.  A blog post I wrote many years ago is the top hit:

http://markphip.blogspot.com/2006/12/mixed-revision-working-copies.html

Subversion merge works a lot better if you have your working copy at a single uniform revision.  So just run update.  The merge wizard will do this for you if you let it.

Answer (score 1):

Outside subclipse, in pure Subversion terms:

You WC may be in Clean state (no local modification), but - in Mixed. Mixed Working Copy will appear, when part of tree updated to revision, different from "Main"

**Step to reproduce**

```
svn co http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/
A    Hello\trunk
...
Checked out revision 34.

cd trunk

svn up -r 30
Updating '.':
...
Updated to revision 30.

cd ..\..

subwcrev Hello
SubWCRev: 'z:\Hello'
Last committed at revision 28
Mixed revision range 30:34
```

"Mixed revision range" is warning for you and for your case. I can't recall can this check and how be done with pure svn client: always use subwcrev in build-tasks

For clean Working Copy (`svn up` in trunk done) subwcrev output

```
subwcrev Hello
SubWCRev: 'z:\Hello'
Last committed at revision 34
Updated to revision 34
```

SubWCRev is part of TortoiseSVN